# How to load XAML content on demand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a bit of a specific question on my hands.

I'm building an app and in current version I have a main xaml Grid element and all other "pages" are also just Grid elements with their visibility attribute being "Hidden".

I'm looking for a way to optimize this and I've made some tests with pages but they didn't really end up being any good as I'm not as experienced with XAML and C#.

Let's say we have our `<Window>` with main `<Grid>` and inside that grid is main content of the app and there's another `<Grid>` with settings (as it is now).
How could I load the content of the Settings Grid as user presses the Settings button and unload it when user closes the settings page.

I've thought of loading it as a page but I don't want user to navigate from main content but have the settings menu as an overlay.

Is there a solution for dynamically loading another XAML file (with settings elements) inside the existing XAML Window?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your On-Demand content in a UserControl, and load UserControl on demand.

```
UserControl1 ctrl = new UserControl1();            
Grid1.Children.Add(ctrl);
```

Few good links :

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W)

[CSharpCorner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/)

Comment: I'm not really sure how exactly to do that.

Comment: i like the idea so far. i'll try it this evening when I get home.

Comment: I tried it and it did exactly what I wanted it too. Loading style data will be a bit tricky but I'll figure that out on the run :) Thank you!

Comment: @DethoRhyne cheers! you can ask your doubts in the room, just mention me.

Comment: sure then.. I have my background/foreground theme Hex colors in Properties of the app. I'm unsure if I can simply bind that to the control without making xaml more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what your trying to accomplish, but to load xaml dynamically try the XamlReader class:

System.Windows.UIElement el = (System.Windows.UIElement)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xaml);

Generally though when I want something hidden until an action occurs I would bind its visibility to a property on a view model, some action would set the value of the property (and fire a propertychangedevent) and the content would be shown.

Comment: That's how I have it now. It's visibility is Hidden until button is pressed and I have made handlers for what is supposed to happen. It's functional, but I realized later on that since there's so much XAML elements it slows down the app a bit on weaker systems. That's why I'm looking for a way to Load each section of the tool only when it's needed and free it up when it's not.